# Undefined class constant VIEW when using the KernelEvents class

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, api-platform.com

I am following a Symfony Api platforms course, now I am working on hashing the password when inserting the user data, to do that, as the course mentionned, a class has been created, it's PasswordHashSubscriber :

```
<?php 

namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use App\Entity\User;
use ApiPlatform\Core\EventListener\EventPriorities;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForControllerResultEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;

class PasswordHashSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

    private $passwordEncoder;

    public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder){
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
    }
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::View => ["hashPassword", EventPriorities::PRE_WRITE]
        ];
    }

    public function hashPassword(GetResponseForControllerResultEvent $event){
        $user = $event->getControllerResult();
        $method = $event->getRequest()->getMethod();

        if(!$user instanceof User || Request::METHOD_POST !== $method){
            return;
        }

        $user->setPassword($this->passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPassword()));
    }
}

?>
```

After creating this class, I try to run this command :

> php bin/console debug:container PasswordHashSubscriber

And what I get is unexpected for me, I get this error that I don't really know how to solve :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Undefined class constant 'View' in C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Learn\symfprojs\correctsymf\src\EventSubscriber\PasswordHashSubscriber.php:22

Which means that the const View of the kernelEvents class is unknown, is it a version problem ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `KernelEvents::VIEW`

Comment: Loool, I spent about 30 min trying to understand what was wrong, it worked Sir, thanks, can you post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as a correct one.